# Parâmetro "connection" do método PivotTableWizard()

Tags: microsoft-excel, vb.net, connectionstring, pivot

Olá, alguém poderia me fornecer um exemplo do uso do apropriado do parâmetro    `connection` do método    `PivotTableWizard()`?

Quando uso esse parâmetro eu recebo o erro:
Não é possível obter a propriedade PivotTableWizard da classe Worksheet.
Eis o código:

```
Dim wb, excel As Object

wb = GetWorkbook(handle, workbook)
excel = wb.Application
Dim ws as Object = GetWorksheet(handle,workbook,worksheetname)
Dim objTable As PivotTable
objTable = ws.PivotTableWizard(,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"ODBC;Provider=MSDASQL.1;Persist Security Info=False;Data Source=SQLexpress;Initial Catalog=PivotChart")
```

Comment: Você não deveria declarar os demais parâmetros?
https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-pivottablewizard-method-excel